# Resolving compiler error CS1519: Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm working on an ASP .NET 2.0 site which uses a Web Application project file, and therefore compiles to a dll rather than deploying the source code as you do with the older style Web Site projects.

The site works fine on my test server (Windows Server 2003 R2, IIS6) when it runs in the root of a website. However I need to run it under a virtual directory instead. When I switch over to that, I get the following error on browsing to any of the pages in the site

CS1519: Invalid token ',' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

The error message goes onto tell me the line number and code file, however the code file is under the Temporary ASP .NET files folder and when I try to find it, it's not there.

As such I'm unable to work out which page is causing the issue although I suspect it could be the master page, if this error occurs on all pages. Has anyone else seen this before or found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was related to inheriting the config settings of the site above mine in the virtual hierarchy.

That site uses a custom profile whose properties are defined under system.web, profile, properties in the config file. The type of one of the properties was specified in the "Namespace.ClassName, AssemblyName" format.

When I removed the ", AssemblyName" from the end, the issue resolved itself, because I'd got rid of the comma that was the invalid token.

I can only assume that, when ASP .NET compiles pages at runtime, it must have been compiling the profile class too, and using the property definitions in the config file during the code generation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't set the virtual as an **application** in IIS, or it is running the wrong version of ASP.NET (i.e. 1.1, when it should be 2.0.blah).

The virtual should have the cog icon in the IIS view, and in the properties pane, must have an application name.

Answer (score 0):

My group mates and I kept having the same issue. The thing is that when you copy a code from somewhere and paste it in Visual Studio, sometimes it adds dots between lines. They are not displayed in Visual Studio, but compiler keeps giving you an error messages, which is in fact frustrating. 
To get rid of them, paste that code snippet in some online compiler. In online compilers those dots are displayed, so you can easily delete them, and then copy & paste the neat code.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace Rectangle
{
    class Name
    {
        int length1;
        int width1;
        int sum;

        Console.Write("Enter the length: ");
            length = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the width: ");
            width = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        sum = length1* width1;

        Console.WriteLine($"Sumis {sum}");

    }
}
```

Comment: To [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18801350) - [a code-only answer is not low-quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358757/1364007). Does it attempt to answer the question? If not, flag as 'not an answer' or recommend deletion (if in the review queue). b) Is it technically incorrect? Downvote or comment.

Comment: Code should be accompanied with a written explanation on how it fixes the issue in the OP.